# sequelize gives different timezone than on the server

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

After I spent a day smashing my head understanding why my sequelize selects calculing times where wrong, I executed this code on localhost, and on the server:

```
const time = await db.Bar.sequelize.query("Select CURRENT_TIME")
console.log("CURRENT_TIME: ", time);
const time3 = await db.Bar.sequelize.query("Select now()")
console.log("Time now: ", time3)
```

It returned this :

> CURRENT_TIME:  [   [ { current_time: '15:00:45.709239+02' } ], .....
>
> Time now:  [   [ { now: 2023-12-06T13:00:45.711Z } ],...

And then when I tried this `select CURRENT_TIME` and `select now()` on postgres pgAdmin4 on localhost and on the server, those returned the right GMT:

> 14:00:30.633552+01:00

The server and localhost were set up for GMT+1

So why does those GMT differences are existing with sequelize?

Comment: The issue is because the client is not always in the same timezone as the server. To fix the problem convert everything to be in UTC time in on the server, then convert that to the user's local time on the client. From the looks of the output `Select now()` is returning a UTC date.

Comment: as I said, The server and localhost are well set up for GMT+1. It sound like a problem from sequelize.
heroku config:get TZ
gives: Europe/Brussels

Comment: everything setup here? https://sequelize.org/api/v7/interfaces/_sequelize_core.index.options#timezone

Answer (score 0):

It had to be set up here

```
sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_DATABASE, process.env.DB_USERNAME, process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        {
            host: process.env.DB_SERVER,
            port: process.env.DB_PORT,
            secure: true,
            dialect: 'postgres',
            timezone: '+01:00',     // here 
            pool: {
                min: 0,
                max: 5,
                idle: 10_000,
                acquire: 30_000
            }
        }
    );
```